# Configuração do CKEDITOR sobrescreve outras

Tags: ckeditor

Na mesma página tenho 2 texarea.
Sendo que um deles é para ser pequeno e o outro padrão.

O padrão possui autogrow e o pequeno seta altura máxima de 100px.

O problema, é que uma configuração sobrescreve a outra.

```
if(cksize == "small"){
    CKEDITOR.config.height = 100;
    CKEDITOR.config.autoGrow_maxHeight = 100;
}else{
    CKEDITOR.config.height = 0;
    CKEDITOR.config.autoGrow_maxHeight = 0;
}
```

Tem como eu passar essa opções no json de opções?

`CKEDITOR.replace(id, options);`

Sendo que dentro dessa `options` teria todas configurações e a altura.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente o autor da pergunta já resolveu seu problema, mas deixarei uma resposta para eventuais dúvidas similares.
Ao chamar `CKEDITOR.config`, você está avisando ao CKEditor que pretende alterar os dados de qualquer instância do CKEditor configurada na atual página. Ou seja, você alterará as configurações das duas instâncias que você criou. 
O que pode ser feito é, ao criar a instância do CKEditor no Textarea, armazenar esta instância em uma variável. Você poderia criar e configurar as duas instâncias desse modo (levando em consideração que o Textarea menor teria o `id='editor1'` e o padrão `id='editor2'`):

```
var editor1 = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
var editor2 = CKEDITOR.replace('editor2');

editor1.config.height = 100;
editor1.config.autoGrow_maxHeight = 100;

editor2.config.height = 0;
editor2.config.autoGrow_maxHeight = 0;
```

Desse modo você também elimina a necessidade do `if`.

Comment: Perfeito, brother. 4 anos depois e ainda ajudando. Rs